# Different selects in one form with same name attribute?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following scenario:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end
```

Categories table has 2 level nesting, for example.
Main category is 'Men', sub-category is 'Accessories' and sub-sub-category is 'Watches'.
[image]

Now when user creates new product he must choose category(**only main category is required**, but he can also chose sub and sub-sub category optional).

My idea is following: I created 3 different select boxes with same name "product[category_id]", so only the last selected value will be sent to the server
through params[:product][:category_id].

```
<div class="col-md-2 main-category">
    <small> Main category? required </small>
    <%= f.select :category_id, 
            Category.where('category_id IS ?', nil).collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]},
            { include_blank: "Select category..." }, 
            id: 'main-category', class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 category-level-1">
    <small> What type? optional </small>
    <%= f.select :category_id, {}, {}, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 category-level-2">
    <small> What type? optional </small>
    <%= f.select :category_id, {}, {}, class: 'form-control' %>
</div>
```

2nd(sub-categories) and 3rd(sub-sub-categories) are initial empty ({}, {}) and hidden through CSS(display: none) and will be populated through ajax call.

```
$('#main-category, .category-level-1 > select').change(function() {
    var selectBox = this.id;
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var url = '/categories/' + selectedValue + '/subcategories';

    $.get(url, function(data) { createSelect(data, selectBox); });
});

function createSelect(data, selectBox) {
  var $currentSelect = null;

  if (selectBox == 'main-category') {
    $('.category-level-1').show();
    $('.category-level-2').hide();
    $('.category-level-1 > select').find('option').remove();

    $currentSelect = $('.category-level-1 > select');
  }
  else {
    $('.category-level-2').show();
    $('.category-level-2 > select').find('option').remove();

    $currentSelect = $('.category-level-2 > select');
  }

  $currentSelect.append('<option selected disabled>Select Category...</option>');
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    $currentSelect.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name +
                          '</option>');
  }
}
```

Where ajax call is sent to following route (categories controller)

```
def subcategories
    id = params[:id]
    @subcategories = Category.where('category_id = ?', id)
    render json: @subcategories 
end
```

So for final result i have following:
[image]

**First of all is it normal to have different inputs in one form with same names created manually like i did in this example?For some reason it seem like 'code-smell' to me. I'm relatively new to rails so wanted to ask am'i violating some good practices with this code?Can you suggest better way to achieve same results?**

Comment: I don't know Rails, but on the browser side if you have multiple form elements with the same name they will _all_ be sent to the server in a standard form submit. I would say this is "normal" if you actually want to use all of the values server-side, but if your Rails code is deliberately ignoring duplicates I'd say that is not a "normal" way to achieve this effect, but if it works... (As a non-Rails guy I can't suggest a better alternative for your project.)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I'm seeing is that since rails takes only the last value, if last select is not selected value will be "" (I am not 100% sure here, but seems logical).

Probably the best way to go would be having a hidden field storing value and being updated when selects change (with proper logic of course)?

Comment: When i move out include_blank from 2nd and 3rd select, i get value from last selected select, which is good for my scenario